# Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In base `build.gradle` `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'` and apk is generating.
after updating gradle to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` getting error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

**base-->build.gradle:**

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

allprojects {

      repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app-->build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories 
{
 maven 
  { 
   url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' 
  }
}
android 
{
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aaaa.aaaa"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.0.0"
    resConfigs "en"
    resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

 lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds true
    abortOnError false
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.controllerConfig
    }
    debug {
        // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
  }

  }

 apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

 dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':volley')
//Google Actions, Base Client Library
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'
//Google App Indexing
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
//Google App Invites
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.0.+'
//Google Analytics
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
//Google Cast
//com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0
//Google Cloud Messaging
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
//Google Drive
// com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0
//Google Fit
// com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0
//Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'

//Sqlite
//compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

//compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
//volley
//compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'

//Fragments n All
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

//Design
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
//List n Card
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.1.1'

//RecyclerView Animation
//compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.recyclerview:recyclerview-animators:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'

//Observable
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.0.7'
//Animation
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
//Event Bus
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
//Material button
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
//Glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
//Fabric
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
//GSon
//gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
//Rate
//compile 'com.kobakei:ratethisapp:0.0.4'
}
```

Could you please guide me to overcome these errors

Comment: show your gradle app file with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official doc in github](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test):

> **Since version 1.1 of the Android Gradle plugin, unit tests in JVM are natively supported. That is why I'm deprecating this plugin and won't be maintaining it further, this means no bug fixes nor enhancements. Thanks for your continuous support all these days.**

Also check [this issue:](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test/issues/104) about your issue:

```
Error:(76, 0) No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
```

> they changed the API for that method. Also they are now supporting unit tests so I won't take the effort to make it work for a version that is supposedly supporting them natively. If their tests don't work quite as expected then either file a report to the tools team or keep using version 1.0.0.
>
> I guess this plug-in is closing to its deprecation

No reason to use this plugin for test today.